# Can't get gulp watch to trigger build function on file change within supposedly watched folder

Tags: javascript, build, gulp, frontend, gulp-watch

I've tried a couple of ways to get gulp to watch a folder of files in order to rebuild on file change and stop me having to do this manually.

I'm sure in grunt this worked just by adding a watch task to the array of build tasks and then it would finish the initial build by leaving watch open to listen for changes during the development session.

I've tried this, which is taken from [this example from the gulp readme](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/docs/readme.md#starting-tasks-on-events) - I've removed the `batch` call as I want the build to trigger on every event.

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch('src/**/*.js', function (events, done) {
        gulp.start('build', done);
    });
});
```

The call to gulp watch works and it appears to be watching, but this error is displayed as soon I make a change to a file in the folder.

My build function works - I've been not so happily triggering it manually so far!

```
/Users/tonileigh/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:89
                    throw new Error('pass strings or arrays of strings');
                          ^
Error: pass strings or arrays of strings
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/tonileigh/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:89:12)
    at /Users/tonileigh/development/shadowcat/gulpfile.js:26:14
    at write (/Users/tonileigh/node_modules/gulp-watch/index.js:123:9)
    at /Users/tonileigh/node_modules/gulp-watch/node_modules/vinyl-file/index.js:52:4
    at /Users/tonileigh/node_modules/gulp-watch/node_modules/vinyl-file/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:76:16
    at fs.js:334:14
    at /Users/tonileigh/node_modules/gulp-watch/node_modules/vinyl-file/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:42:10
    at /Users/tonileigh/node_modules/gulp-watch/node_modules/chokidar/node_modules/readdirp/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:42:10
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:95:15)
```

I've also tried this, based on [this example from the gulp readme](https://github.com/floatdrop/gulp-watch/blob/master/docs/readme.md#incremental-build):

```
jsxToJs = function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
    .pipe(watch('src/**/*.js'))
    .pipe(react())
    .pipe(concat('javascript.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
}
```

I'm probably mistaken, but I'm expecting this to watch the glob for changes and apply the function. The function takes some JSX and converts into raw JS with ReactJS then concats all the files it finds into a single js file.

It doesn't error, but I get a new directory in my root that follows the pattern in the glob, creating a new compiled example of the saved file

My full file, without my two above attempts, is here:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    react = require('gulp-react'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),

    jsxToJs = function() {
      gulp.src('src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(react())
        .pipe(concat('javascript.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    },

    scssToCss = function() {
      gulp.src('src/style.scss')
        .pipe(sass('style.css').on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
    };

gulp.task('jsxToJs', jsxToJs);
gulp.task('styles', scssToCss);
gulp.task('js', ['jsxToJs', 'concat']);
gulp.task('build', ['jsxToJs', 'styles']);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to find some Yeoman generators with gulp and install them
2. Use this code

```
    gulp = require('gulp);
    var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
    var browserSync = require('browser-sync);
    var reload = browserSync.reload;

    gulp.task('mysupertask', function () {
        gulp.watch('src/**/*.js').on('change', reload);
    });
```

this will reload each time you make changes to your js. You can make some build task and add it to your script like this:

```
...
gulp.task('mybuildtask, function() {
    gulp.src('src/**/*.coffee')
    .pipe($.coffee())
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/scripts'));
});

gulp.task('mysupertask', function () {
    gulp.watch('src/**/*.js').on('change', ['mybuildtask'],reload);
});
```

and you can run all this by `gulp mysupertask`

> not sure about mybuildtask string syntax